# How to bind crystal report to manually created DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I wan't to create DataSet from code and set it as data source for crystal report.
I don't want to create a DataSet xsd file in VS if I don't have to. Just pure code.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
DataColumn cln = new DataColumn();
// I fill row, columns, table and add it to ds object
...
```

Then when I need report I use:

```
myReport.SetDataSource(ds);
```

The problem here is I don't know how to bind this to report? How to add fields?
I have a text and binary data (image).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is only way out. As suggested by rosado. Little bit explained
1. CReate a RPT File. 
2. Create a XSD with the desired columns.
3. Drag drop the columns on the rpt. Format it as required.
4. Now create connection, use adapter to fill that dataset.
5. Filling u dataset will automatically fill the report columns.

Below is a sample code from one of mine project.

```
Invoice invoice = new Invoice(); // instance of my rpt file
var ds = new DsBilling();  // DsBilling is mine XSD
var table2 = ds.Vendor;
var adapter2 = new VendorTableAdapter();
adapter2.Fill(table2);                   

var table = ds.Bill;
var adapter = new BillTableAdapter();
string name = cboCustReport.Text;
int month = int.Parse(cboRptFromMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());
int year = int.Parse(cboReportFromYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
adapter.Fill(table, name,month,year);

ds.AcceptChanges();

invoice.SetDataSource(ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = invoice;
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Yep, feels little bit dirty, but it's the only way (from what I know)

Comment: This is the only way I have been able to do it as well.  We would create a blank dataset with the tables, columns, etc and use the write to xml method so that you would get an xml file with the data set schema in it.  You would bind that to the report so it would know about the available columns, etc.  Then in code you would fill the dataset with actual data and bind it to the report data source.  It was the only way we could get datasets to work with crystal reports.  Very hacky but it worked.

Comment: Yep, Only way I know from last 6 years ;) don't know if any body else invented any thing new

Answer (score 4):

try like this...

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   oleAdapter.Fill(ds);
   ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
   rpt.load();
   rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]); 
   this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Comment: No. Maybe I didn't explained it right in my question. The problem here is I made and pass this data set manually. So I can't drag and drop field to my report to display passed data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dataset object (.xsd) in visual studio and  fill it with one or many datatables containing the SAME field names you got on your `DataSet ds = new DataSet();`

Then go to your .rpt file: database fields -> database expert - > project data -> ADO.Net DataSets, then select the dataset you just created and design the report as you want.

Use the report as usual.

```
myReport.SetDataSource(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use dummy image data column namely Photo, to store file system Images into data base table
GlobalVar.sql = " SELECT rollno AS reg_no, CAST(0xADB AS image) As Photo FROM mast_roll Where Rollno IN ('120512','120518')  ";
GlobalVar.da = new OleDbDataAdapter(GlobalVar.sql, GlobalVar.con);
GlobalVar.ds = new DataSet();
GlobalVar.da.Fill(GlobalVar.ds, "st_detail");

// load photo into data table
foreach (DataRow dr in GlobalVar.ds.Tables["st_detail"].Rows)
{
// complete path of photo file
    imgPath = @"D:\ImageSt\" + dr["reg_no"].ToString() + ".jpg";
    // read photo from file
    FsImage = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    // convert image file to array
    byte[] PhotoArr;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        FsImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        PhotoArr = ms.ToArray();
    }
    // update photo
    dr["photo"] = PhotoArr;
    // end array conversion
}
// end loading
```