# Create crystal report using dataset without using xsd file

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I would like to ask if it is possible to create a crystal report using a dataset without  using or creating an xsd file. Because there's one report here that does that. It is connected to a dataset but there's no xsd file that is used.

Comment: Please find the link below

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset

Comment: does this mean that it is impossible to do one? because i find it weird....

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, just use the report document's SetDataSource method :

```
YourReportDocument.SetDataSource(YourDS);
```