# Create Crystal Report from manual dataset in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, xsd, dataset

I need to create a crystal report from just created Dataset.
My steps:

1) Created Dataset XSD (MainData.xsd) file with same number of columns that I have in my application DataSet.
2) Created Crystal Report in VS2010, Using wizard selected Datasets ADO.NET-> Selected mine Dataset XSD file.
3) Fetched mine dataset from another class.
4) Copy mine dataset to XSD.
5)

Here is peace of code:

```
try
{
   MainReport rep1 = new MainReport(); // MainReport name of CR
   MainData data = mainData; //MainData - XSD file. mainData - local dataset
   rep1.SetDataSource(data); //<-- this line application stucks
   crystaReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ...
}
```

At the line  **rep1.SetDataSource(data);** application stucks, nothing is caught by try-catch. Any suggestions?

Comment: having data in "data" Dataset? check using Debugging.

Comment: The Answer By Amit Ranjan on this page may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset/8420629#8420629