# Single Report from different tables in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I'm doing an assignment.It's called rate analysis.I successfully coded the project on vb.net.
Now i wanted to move on the reporting phase.

Now i have totally 8 tables in the db,and out of the 8 i wanted 5 tables for the report.

I got the project,work item,work_item_material,work_item_labor and work_item_equipment tables.[image]
The other 3 that i don't want (for the report) are material,equipment and labor tables.

How do i do the reporting since i never did the report from multiple tables.I there a way to merge the tables,since i want to pull information for a certain project.[image]

Comment: send me a message.i can some time help you

Answer (score 0):

Create procedure and use it with dataset,then call that dataset into your report.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMultipleTableData
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT     AccTrn.TrnKy, AccMas.AccKy, EmpMas.EmpKy, Address.AdrCd, ItmMas.ItmCd, AccTrn.TrnNo, EmpMas.EmpNo, ItmMas.fInAct, ItmMas.fApr
FROM         EmpMas INNER JOIN
                      Address INNER JOIN
                      AccTrn ON Address.AdrKy = AccTrn.AdrKy INNER JOIN
                      ItmMas ON AccTrn.TrnKy = ItmMas.ItmKy INNER JOIN
                      AccMas ON AccTrn.AccTrnKy = AccMas.AccKy ON EmpMas.EmpKy = Address.AdrKy
END
GO
```

Comment: I kind of came up with an sql statement that selects the records from the tables,but in the crystal reports viewer it displays every record in a separate page,which makes it a little bulky.

Comment: Check this links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpycT0CZohg