# How to bind a Dataset to CrystalReport in C#

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports

I have a database and I want to use some couple of its tables in my report (Crystal Report),
in my code I have

```
        testdbDataSet ds = new testdbDataSet();

        testdbDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter productAdapter = new testdbDataSetTableAdapters.ProductsTableAdapter();
        productAdapter.Fill(ds.Products);

        testdbDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter regionAdapter = new testdbDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter();
        regionAdapter.Fill(ds.Region);  

        ds.AcceptChanges();

        ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
        reportDoc.FileName = "CrystalReport1.rpt";
        reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDoc;
        crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```

- ds is an instance of a .XDS Dataset

the crystalReportViewer does not show my report

Ive checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset/8420629#8420629) link on stackoverflow but could not get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    testdbDataSet ds = new testdbDataSet();

    //FETCH FROM ANYWHERE TO a DataTable
    DataTable _DtFrmDBPrd = new DataTable();
    DataTable _DtFrmDBRgn = new DataTable();

    _DtFrmDBPrd = GetDataFrmDBPrd();//Filling the DataTable From DB or any where..
    _DtFrmDBRgn = GetDataFrmDBRgn();

    ds.Products.Merge(_DtFrmDBPrd);//Both the Data Table should have the same column name and Data Type
    ds.Region.Merge(_DtFrmDBRgn);

    ReportDocument reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
    reportDoc.FileName = "CrystalReport1.rpt";
    reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDoc;
    crystalReportViewer1.Show();
```