# Display untyped DataSet to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

How to display untyped DataSet content in the crystal reports.

My requirement: User needs to see the report before sending it, so I do not want to save it in DB before sending it. So I want to display the content of the DataSet into report. Following is a workaround I tried:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("Mac", "GeorgeTown");
dt.Rows.Add("Terry", "Russia");
dt.Rows.Add("George", "India");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument orpt = 
    new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
orpt.Load(MapPath("CrystalReport3.rpt"));
orpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = orpt;
```

Comment: Include relevant details in your question specifying what happens when you run this code. Is it giving any error or asking for LogOnInfo or something else. In case of error what error you are getting

Comment: this just diplay an empty report , because the report has no fields / If it was typed dataset then i can get the fields in report's field explorer. but as its untyped dataset, am not getting how to add the fields to the reports.

Comment: You'll have to design your report using Typed Dataset but you can pass your data from code behind. Check [how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset)