# How can I create a report from an autogenerate datatable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset

Good afternoon, this is my problem.

I had created a datatable in C# with all the columns i needed, all this on runtime, and displayed all on a grid, all that works fine. Now my end user is asking me to put all that data on an report, but because this is not a table on the SQL i can't create a crystal report like i used to, making connections or using the wizard, so is there a way to create a crystal report or any other kind of report on runtime with autogenerated columns? I'm thinking on exporting to Excel too but i want to be sure i have no other option.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, is a little rusty.

Comment: Yes, using a DataSet, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset

Comment: Thanks for the link Rodolfo, but that info is assuming that i already have a crystal report file created, yes?, or maybe i'm wrong, i mean, there is already a rpt file and it only need the dataset / datatable as a parameter. I want to know if i can create all the report without having a rpt file on my project, from scratch, and then pass the data already collected and formated. I don't know if i'm getting all the idea, sorry for that, my english is not that tecnical :(

Comment: You can't generate a report without and .rpt file, at least you wanna build it all programatically, and that's insane. I don't understand why you can't create a Report skipping the wizard, a blank one with a table, and then you pass the DataSet, look this another example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/crystal-report-without-database-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Ok, got it, so the recommendation is to create a blank report with an empty structure and then use it to build the distribution of the columns, and then with the dataset send the data in. I was thinking that maybe there was a way to do it but maybe you are right, its quite insane. Thanks for the tip Rodolfo :D

Comment: Yes, skip the wizard, add a blank report, add a table and follow the guide to pass the DataSet (your data) to the report, and that's it.

Comment: The table that i will use to creat a blank report has to have all the same columns that i generate on the dataset? or just with a couple of columns would do the trick?