# C# windows Crystal Reports, How to display a data table in crystal reports programmatically

Tags: c#, database, windows

Here is my code, I get an error when running the code.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Worker ";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectonString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();
    cr.SetDataSource(dt);

    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate Question:
[How to Bind Crystal Report to manually created Dataset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Question:
[How to Bind Crystal Report to manually created Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341272/how-to-bind-crystal-report-to-manually-created-dataset)

You need to do something like this:

```
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice(); // instance of my rpt file
            var ds = new DsBilling();  // DsBilling is mine XSD
            var table2 = ds.Vendor;
            var adapter2 = new VendorTableAdapter();
            adapter2.Fill(table2);


            var table = ds.Bill;
            var adapter = new BillTableAdapter();
            string name = cboCustReport.Text;
            int month = int.Parse(cboRptFromMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());
            int year = int.Parse(cboReportFromYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
            adapter.Fill(table, name,month,year);

            ds.AcceptChanges();

            invoice.SetDataSource(ds);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = invoice;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```