# How to transfer datatable or datagridview to crystal report, note that the data in datagridview are changeable rows and columns

Tags: vb.net

How to transfer datatable or datagridview to crystal report, note that the data in datagridview are changeable rows and columns??

```
        Dim dtFinal As New DataTable()

        For i As Integer = 0 To DGVresults.ColumnCount - 1
            dtFinal.Columns.Add(DGVresults.Columns(i).HeaderText, System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
            'DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(PositionFromLoop, NewColumnFromGeneratedString)
        Next
        For j As Integer = 0 To DGVresults.RowCount - 1
            Dim dr As DataRow = dtFinal.NewRow()
            For i As Integer = 0 To DGVresults.ColumnCount - 1
                dr.Item(i) = DGVresults.Rows(j).Cells(i).Value
            Next
            dtFinal.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtFinal

        Dim reportDocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        reportDocument = New CrystalReport1
        reportDocument.SetDataSource(dtFinal)
        RptResults.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument

        RptResults.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: See [How to bind crystal report to manually created DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8341272/719186)

Comment: thanks for replay, i am not asking how to create dataset, i am asking how to transfer datagridview to crystal report!!

Comment: What LarsTech was trying to say is that you need a dataset to make a crystal report :) if you have random rows and columns how is crystal report going to know how to organize your data?

Comment: You mean that i have to fill DGV into Dataset, and then transfer DS to Crystal report??

Comment: It doesn't have to be a DataSet.  The DataTable would work, too.  Not much experience with Crystal Reports, but the link shows how you set the report to the DataTable.  Try it.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech, I'll try it.

Comment: I posted my code so far,

Comment: The grid isn't using a DataTable as the DataSource?  If not, it probably should,  Then you could just transfer over the same DataTable to the report.  It's a little confusing because you have DGVresults and a DataGridView1.